# How to Deserialize an xml element with only attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, windows, windows-phone-8

I am using System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer class.I need to Deserialize the following XML in C#:

```
<message from="abc" to="xyz" xml:lang="en" id="Vx4Ix-14" type="chat">
   <received xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts" id="9beea4d7-aa1e-4f3c-929c-712b56164b63"/>
</message>
```

Following is my Class to deserialize it :

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "message")]
public class Message
  {
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "from")]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "to")]
    public string To { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xml:lang")]
    public string Language { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "received", Namespace = "urn:xmpp:receipts")]
    public Received Received { get; set; } 
}

public class Received
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

The "received" xml element has only attributes and I want te deserialize that element to get "id" value of that element.
But when I use the above class to Deserialize , I get all the values except "id" attribute value of "received" xml element. I get the value of Received property as null.

Please let me know what is wrong with my class?

This is my Deserializer Method:

```
   public static T Deserialize<T>(string xml)
    {
        T deserializedObject = default(T);
        try
        {

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                deserializedObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }
            return deserializedObject;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return deserializedObject;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tested your classes in a simple VS2015 console application (not windows phone) and it works perfectly. How does your deserializing code looks like?

Comment: I have updated the question with deserializer method which I used. You are right, something is wrong with my method. A console application works just fine.

Comment: I just tried your "Deserialize" method and also works OK for me in a console application. Can you show the code you are using to invoke "Deserialize"?

Comment: XMLSerializer.Deserialize<Message>(strXML). I am using it like this.

Comment: I suppose the "strXML" value is exactly the same at the begining of your question and that you assign the returned value to a variable also to check the value... Maybe the problem is in the windows phone flavour.

Comment: I got my mistake. While defining "Received" attribute in "Message" class using [XmlElement(ElementName = "received", Namespace = "urn:xmpp:receipts")], I had added an extra space in the namespace before "xmpp" ("urn:    xmpp:receipts). Because of that extra space serializer was not able to deserialize it properly.  But while posting the question I removed that space somehow. Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: its working fine! no issues in windows phone 8 vs2013

Answer (score 0):

Your class looks good and also works for me. Maybe you're not using the deserializer correctly!? I successfully tried it with your XML like this:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Message));
var message = (Message)serializer.Deserialize(
    new FileStream(@"C:\Users\homann.k\Desktop\test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
```

Comment: I have updated the question with deserializer method which I used. Can you please check whats wrong with it?